# Does sql server automatically solve the classic readers-writers dilemma?

Tags: sql-server, computer-science

I am taking an operating systems class where we just learned about the '[readers and writers'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem) problem: how do you deal with multiple processes that want to read and write from the same memory (at the same time)? I'm also dealing with a version of this problem at work: I am writing an application that requires multiple users to read and write to a shared SQL server database.  Because the 'readers and writers' problem seems so well understood and discussed, I'm assuming that Microsoft has solved it for me. Meaning, that I don't need  to worry about setting permissions or configuring SQL server to ensure that people are not reading and writing to a database at the same time. Specifically, can I assume that, with SQL server 2005,  by default:

1. No process reads while another process is writing
2. No two processes write at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A writer will take an exclusive `X` lock on at least the row(s) they are modifying and will hold this until their transaction commits. `X` locks are incompatible with other `X` locks so two writers can not concurrently modify the same row.

A reader will (at default read committed isolation level) take a shared lock and release this as soon as the data is read. This is incompatible with an `X` lock so readers must wait for writing transactions to finish before reading modified data. SQL Server also has [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130975.aspx) in which readers are not blocked by writers but instead read an earlier version of the row.

Answer (score 2):

Classic SQL Servers like MS-SQL use a pessimistic approach and lock rows, tables or pages until a writing operation is done. You really don't have to cope with that, because -- as you said -- the creator already solved that problem. Have a look at [this article](http://mssqlserver.wordpress.com/2006/11/08/locks-in-sql/) for some first information, any database book will cover the problem in depth. If you are interested in this topic, I would suggest reading "Database Systems" by Connolly and Begg, for example.